# NodeJS backend receives empty request body from Ionic frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, ionic-framework, ionic2

I created an Ionic app (Angular2) with Node backend. My app has something called `Level`, and a `Level` has its `title`. I have a list of levels with the plus sign which opens a modal for adding a new level. When the "Save" button is clicked, the modal is dismissed, and a service (Ionic provider) method is called, which then calls the backend endpoint.

However, I noticed that every document which is stored in MongoDB has only ID and no title. Further, I discovered that the everything is fine until the backend is called - if I do `console.log`, I can see the title that has been entered. But when I output the request on the backend, there's nothing in the request body.

Here are the relevant files:

**`frontend/src/pages/admin-level-list/admin-level-list.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LevelComponent } from '../../components/level/level';
import { LevelProvider } from '../../providers/level/level';
import { AddLevelPage } from '../add-level/add-level';
import { EditLevelPage } from '../edit-level/edit-level';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-admin-level-list',
  templateUrl: 'admin-level-list.html',
})
export class AdminLevelListPage {
  levels: any;    
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public levelService: LevelProvider, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {    
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.levelService.getLevels().then((data) => {
      this.levels = data;
      // The data is loaded correctly, but only with ID's, no titles
      // (because the titles are not stored in the DB at all)
    });
  }

  addLevel() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddLevelPage);
    modal.onDidDismiss(level => {
      if (level) {
        this.levels.push(level);
        this.levelService.createLevel(level);
      }
    });
    modal.present();
  }
}
```

**`frontend/src/pages/admin-level-list/admin-level-list.html`**

```
...
<button ion-button icon-only (click)="addLevel()">
  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</button>
...
```

**`frontend/src/providers/level/level.ts`**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LevelProvider {
  data: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.data = null;
  }

  createLevel(level) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // ***** I'M LOGGING THE DATA HERE !!! *****
    console.dir(JSON.stringify(level));
    // ***** THE OUTPUT IS: *****
    // ***** {"title":"Exactly what I have entered"} *****
    // ***** ...SO I GUESS ALL IS FINE UNTIL NOW *****
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/levels', JSON.stringify(level), { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.dir(res);
      });
  }
}
```

**`frontend/src/pages/add-level/add-level.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-level',
  templateUrl: 'add-level.html',
})
export class AddLevelPage {
  title: any;
  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
  }

  save(): void {
    let level = {
      title: this.title
    };
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(level);
  }

  close(): void {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

**`frontend/src/pages/add-level/add-level.html`**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Title</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="title" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button full color="secondary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</ion-content>
```

**`backend/server.js`**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/kursnemackog');

app.use(morgan('dev')); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());   
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

var Level = mongoose.model('Level', {
    title: String
});

app.post('/api/levels', function (req, res) {
    // ***** I'M LOGGING THE REQUEST HERE !!! *****
    console.log(req);
    // ***** ITS BODY IS EMPTY !!!!! *****
    // ***** IncomingMessage {       *****
    // ***** ...                     *****
    // ***** params: {},             *****
    // ***** query: {},              *****
    // ***** ...                     *****
    // ***** body: {},               *****
    // ***** ...                     *****
    Level.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        done: false
    }, function (err, level) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        Level.find(function (err, levels) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(levels);
        });
    });
});

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
```

Does anyone know why is nothing passed to the backend?
Please let me know if you need any additional data/code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! In `level.ts` instead of sending `JSON.stringify(level)`, I sent only `level`, and now there is the `title` field in the body.